# Changing the cursor when hovering a Gtk::Image

Tags: c++, gtk, cursor, mouse

I've implemented a "clickable" Gtk::Image in my application by wrapping it in a Gtk::EventBox and watching for the button-press-event.

I now want to make the mouse cursor change to a hand when the image is hovered, but I can't find a way to do it. I attempted to use get_window()->set_cursor(). But both the Gtk::Image and Gtk::EventBox return a null pointer (which probably isn't that surprising).

How can I change the cursor while the image is hovered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import gtk

window = gtk.Window ()
box = gtk.EventBox ()
image = gtk.image_new_from_file ('trollface.jpg')

window.add (box)
box.add (image)

window.show_all ()
window.present ()
image.window.set_cursor (gtk.gdk.Cursor (gtk.gdk.HAND1))

window.connect ('destroy', lambda *ignored: gtk.main_quit ())

gtk.main ()
```

I suppose it's the same in Gtkmm as in PyGTK.

Comment: Thanks, the reason it wasn't working for me was the image has to be "realized" before get_window() returns anything. Calling set_cursor from the "realize" signal works fine.